# Java Superclass get parameter value from subclass

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

The Question is:

1) How can i get subclass parameter values to superclass?

2) i want to take the name(From subclass) for collection.sort , like this.model.compareTo(other.model).   However, I don't know how to get the "Name" Value from subclass and do the collection.sort.

** Is it correct to write public int compareTo(Car other, Taxi other2)??? **

Here is the code:

```
 public class Car implement comparable <Car>() 
 {
 private string model;
 private int price;


 public car(String model , int price)
{
   this.model=model;
   this.price=price;
 } 

    ............some getmethod here..........

  public int compareTo (Car other)  
  {
        ** Want to sort by name , like this.model.compareTo(other.model)**
  }


 }
```

**Taxi.java:**

```
public class taxi extends Car ()
{
     private string name;
     public taxi (String model , int price, String name)
     { 
         super(model, price);
         this.name = name; 
     }
       ......some getmethod here..........
}
```

Comment: If your superclass does not use "name", then why does it need to be defined there?

Comment: maybe i just want to use the name in the superclass.... but i don't know how to call the name value to be used in superclass

Comment: because i need to do collection sorting with "this.name.compareTo(other.name)"

Comment: Sorry  typing mistake

Comment: he just forgot the extend. Please tell us more about your collection sorting. Why does it need to be in the Car and not in Taxi ?

Comment: You already know how to pass stuff to the super class, like you did with `model` and `price`, but you're unable to do the same with `name`?

Comment: modified again. Can anyone tell me how to do the collection.sort with name

Comment: How will you sort two cars by name if neither of them has a name?

Answer (score 0):

you can use subclass values by creating object of sub class in superclass.
It is also known as delegation.

Comment: you mean Taxi taxi = new Taxi ()?   but shouldn't it add parameter inside?

Comment: where can i put the new instance

Comment: in super class. make an object of class car.